# Using Unix find `pwd`

Tags: python, unix, find, pwd

I am trying to use the Unix `find` command in Python and can't get to input `pwd`, `` `pwd` `` did not work either.

```
import commands
import os

f = raw_input('Enter name of the file: ')
fh = open(f, 'r')

prevdir = os.getcwd()
files = fh.readlines()

for line in files:
    os.chdir(line)
    print commands.getoutput('find `pwd` -name "*.txt"')
    # print commands.getoutput('find \`pwd\` -name "*.txt"')
```

Comment: your commands.getoutput line works for me. did you try it in the Python shell?

Comment: As others suggested, there are almost definitely methods in Python to do what you're trying to do -- e.g. `os.listdir`, `os.walk`, the `glob` module, etc.  But if you were committed to this approach, you could also do something like `commands.getoutput('find "%s" -name "*.txt"' % os.getcwd())`.  `print` that string that I'm suggesting you pass to `getoutput` to see what it does.

Comment: You are rite, it does work in python shell.I am running this program in tcsh. Dont know if that has any thing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put it out as an alternative.

Assuming you only want to search in the one directory (ie. not recursive) I would rather try using `glob` (assuming line ends with `/`, otherwise that would need to be added to the string):

```
import glob
for line in files:
    print(glob.glob(line+"*.txt"))
```

if recursive (Python3.5>):

```
import glob
for line in files:
    print(glob.glob(line+"**/*.txt"),recursive=True)
```

Comment: Also better since this is a platform independent solution, unlike mine. Mine will only ever run on *Nix systems, your's will work on Windows.

+1.